# Unable to call function on prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I'm not exactly sure what the problem here is... `oneTime` is an array that only contains "init"; `doLoop` is an array that only contains "update"; When I try to call the function from `oneTime` it generates the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined`. If, in that same spot, I log `this` to the console, the prototype shows the init function as expected.

The really weird part, to me anyway, is that the functions called in exactly the same way from `doLoop` execute just fine.

Any ideas?

```
    State.prototype.run = function() {
        let _that = this;

    // Case 1
        for (var a = 0; a < oneTime.length; a++) {
            this.prototype[oneTime[a]]();
        }

    // Case 2
        for (var a = 0; a < oneTime.length; a++) {
            _that.prototype[oneTime[a]]();
        }

    // Case 3
        !function() {
            for (var a = 0; a < oneTime.length; a++) {
                _that.prototype[oneTime[a]]();
            }
        }();

    // Case 4
        this.run.intervala = setInterval(function() {
            for (var a = 0; a < oneTime.length; a++) {
                _that.prototype[oneTime[a]]();
            }
        }, 1000 / fps);

    // Case 5
        this.run.interval = setInterval(function() {
            for (var a = 0; a < doLoop.length; a++) {
                _that.prototype[doLoop[a]]();
            }
        }, 1000 / fps);
    }
```

-- EDIT --
Did some more playing around... Cases 1, 2, and 3 all return `Cannot read property 'init' of undefined` However, Case 4 executes just fine... albeit in a loop. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not an answer, but I have noticed `fps` word in your code. If you are trying to do animation, then `setInterval` is definitely wrong way to do this. It is unreliable (doesn't guarantee to maintain interval) and is not designed for drawing with small intervals. Use `requestAnimationFrame` instead.